# How to switch between two postgres connection strings using MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql

I am wondering how I can achieve the function that if my first connection to a postgres database times out, the program tries the second one during run time.

The two connection strings connects to two different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my question:

```
    public class DbConnection
{
    private static string _connectionString;

    private static string GetConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return _connectionString ?? (_connectionString = SelectConnectionString());
        }
    }

    private static string SelectConnectionString()
    {
        try
        {

            Database db = new Database("Your connection string");
            db.OpenSharedConnection();//this is petapoco ORM function
            db.CloseSharedConnection();
            return "Your connnection string name";
        }
        catch
        {
            return "LocalConnection";
        }
    }

    public static Database TestDbConnection()
    {
        return new Database(GetConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really see the value of doing such a thing. As I clarified with my boss, the final solution to my project is way simpler than this and is actually a different question.The final solution is basically set up the connection string inside the Web.Release.config file.